# Backup and Restore User

Tags: 2010, backup, user-accounts

I have SharePoint 2010 and would like to know if it is possible to change the user in charge of performing Backup and Restore routines. I recently changed most users to non local administrator and would like to know if this one can be a local administrator.

Comment: What kind of Backup/Restore is it SQL database or SharePoint. Does it use PowerShell CmdLets?

Comment: SharePoint Central Administration;s Backup and restore.